What is the difference between decomposition we use over data over time and Empirical Mode Decomposition (EMD)?
let's say I have data over time (i.e. signal of activity of my laptop CPU over time) and I want to do some characteristic analytics on top of this time-series data. So I know that I can decompose the time data into its own time elements (Trend, seasonality, irregulities\noise) using statsmodels python package docs








Time Series Decomposition In Python. ref



but I was wondering if it makes sense to apply Empirical Mode Decomposition (EMD) to this time-series data using emd python package docs for further investigation, and check the results of Intrinsic Mode Functions (IMFs) if represent meaningful components of the original elements of the signal.
I'm not sure since playing with IMFs based on emd.sift.sift() could be used for analysing Compute activities like CPU usage in local\virtual machine or just make sense for those signals that can be transit\convert between position - velocity - acceleration info we know from physics course?
import numpy as np
import emd

# Apply EMD to decompose the position time series into IMFs
imfs = emd.sift.sift(position_time_series)

# Calculate velocities by differentiating each IMF with respect to time
# Assuming constant time step (e.g., dt = time[1] - time[0])
dt = time[1] - time[0]
velocities = np.gradient(imfs, dt, axis=1)

# ....

I would be happy if you could comment on this question if EMD could be meaningful or useful for CPU utilization use cases and characterization analytics.

Which elements EMD could offer fit to characteristics of time data?
Is it comparable with those time elements shown in the above picture?

